# Replace items in list if condition

Tags: python-2.7

I need to replace temperature values in list depends on negative/positive and get rid of float at the same time. I.e. value '-0.81' should be '-1' (round) or '0.88' should be '1'.

```
myList = ['-1.02', '-1.03', '-0.81', '-0.17', '-0.07', '0.22', '0.88', '0.88', '0.69']
for i in range (len(myList)):
    if myList[i][0] == '-' and int(myList[i][-2]) > 5:
       do sth...
```

At the end I need new list with new values. Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already almost there. It's not necessary to reference the elements by index.

```
myList = ['-1.02', '-1.03', '-0.81', '-0.17', '-0.07', '0.22', '0.88', '0.88', '0.69']
for i in myList:
    if i[0] == '-' and int(i[-2]) > 5:
       do sth...
```

If all you want to do is rounding then you can use a list comprehension.

```
roundlist = [round(float(i)) for i in myList]
```

Comment: However, be careful with the behavior of `round()` function

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the string into number, check for rounding (whether the decimal is higher or lower than 0.5), and convert it back to string

```
import math 

myList = ['-1.02', '-1.03', '-0.81', '-0.17', '-0.07', '0.22', '0.88', '0.88', '0.69']
result = [0] * len(myList)

for i in range (len(myList)):
    num = float(myList[i])
    if num - math.floor(num) < 0.5:
        result[i] = str(math.floor(num)) # round down
    else:
        result[i] = str(math.ceil(num)) # round up
print(result)
```

Comment: Is there a possibilty to remove from result negative char from '-0.0' and strip every item after the first digit?

Comment: You could convert the float to integer to strip every item after the first digit. As of removing '-' from '-0.0', you can do a check, if the value is 0, then use `abs()`